# Facebook api search without keyword

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an application that searches for events near you. I need to search everything of type event from a specific date to another one. So I use this graph API query:

```
search?q=cluj&type=event&since=2015-12-05&until=2015-12-06&city=Cluj-Napoca
```

Now the problem is the `q=` thing is annoying me more than helping since I don't get all the events cause I'm missing a keyword.

Now the question is how can I search for all events between those 2 dates since I need to have something there at all time?

Comment: You can’t; the API does not provide that kind of search capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graph API doesn't support such queries. But you can have a look at

- https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location

which uses a combined approach (Place search by location & events lookup by returned places).